# FunctionFlip doesn't work. Alternative/fix?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I am on OS X 10.9.5 and recently (can't remember if this happened during 10.9.4 or not)

[FunctionFlip](http://kevingessner.com/software/functionflip/) has started to work very inconsistently for me.

Basically I use this to enable the F1-F10 keys for use in terminal (and some of them I set to do stuff like next/prev. tab e.g. in web browser) and I used FunctionFlip to generally enable the volume control keys so that they work globally.

But lately it's just not been "kicking in" so it's hit and miss every time i try to change the volume.

Answer (score 2):

I got tired of FunctionFlip not working right and finally found Karbiner does exactly what I want and works great.

Answer (score 1):

[Fluor](https://github.com/Pyroh/Fluor) is a relative newcomer to this space. I'm not sure if it's exactly what you want because it doesn't allow you to assign the functionality on a per key basis - it's either all F keys or all apple functions:

> Fluor is a tool that allows you to automatically change the behaviour of the keyboard's fn keys depending on the active application.

But it is open source, works on macOs Sierra and is actively developed (as of March 2017).

Comment: I've been using Karabiner for this job (more reliable than BTT). Good to know though.

Answer (score 0):

I had an insight about 2 sentences into typing this question. BetterTouchTool has global keyboard shortcut functionality (in fact I already use BTT for app-specific keyboard shortcuts), which turns out works perfectly for this by binding the F11 and F12 keys. Even more awesome, I can also use it to set app-specific shortcuts, and this lets me override so I can assign these two keys to other functions when I am in iTerm!

BTT is 100% necessary for OSX and I don't understand why Apple hasn't taken the hint and integrated its functionality into the OS. However, i am glad that this has not been done because BTT is pretty much overflowing with features to explore.