# Assign function key to Debug ("Step Into") in Mac Excel Visual Basic Editor

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, developer-program, office-365

I've tried many things to assign a 1-key shortcut to the "Step Into" debugging function in the VBA editor for Mac Excel (Mac VBE). I posted a question [about this on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57991954/assign-f8-to-debug-step-into-shortcut-in-mac-vbe) but my experience is that Macintosh-related questions often don't get resolved there, as in this case.

Below are screenshots showing an attempt to reassign to the `F8` key (which is used in Windows for this). Although it looks like it would work, pressing the key does nothing when debugging (although the awkward default `shift-cmd-i` still works).  There are other 'solutions' to this kind of problem which do not work for me. Namely, using the FN key in combination with `F8` or checking the "Use `F1`,`F2`,etc. keys as standard function keys" checkbox within Settings.  I've also tried using a utility called FunctionFlip, but [like others](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151061/functionflip-doesnt-work-alternative-fix), it didn't work for me.

[image]

[image]

I'm not tied to `F8`, and would be happy to reassign others such as `F5`, `F6` or `F7` which are already used within the Mac VBE. I say this because according to a [comment by Emilio](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/265062/can-i-run-spotify-by-pressing-my-f8-button-instead-of-itunes) `F8` is special on the Mac. But when I tried with `F5`, for example, it also failed.

I'm using Excel 16.29.1 on an Office 365 Personal subscription on a MacBook pro without a touch panel (which I understand replaces the function keys), and I use both notebook keyboard and an external (mac) keyboard purchased in 2019.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-custom-keyboard-shortcut-for-office-for-mac-6bbeb90e-96d9-4e03-b199-fc026ebdc321

Comment: Interesting question! :) I've never customised a keyboard shortcut for the Visual Basic Editor. And that, by the way, is why you're having problems. Basically you're trying to customise a shortcut in MS Excel, but even the **shift** + **cmd** + **I** shortcut doesn't work in Excel. In VBE yes, but in Excel no. And while you can customise keyboard shortcuts in Excel *within* Excel, I don't think there's a similar option for the VBE. I'll have to see if I can find a way around this conundrum. BTW, what exact version of Excel are you using? And, if the 16.x series, are you on a 365 subscription?

Comment: @Monomeeth Details about the Excel I'm using are now added to my post. I tested changing the shortcut within the Excel app to show/hide the Ribbon to F5 or F6 and that worked fine (F8 didn't work). But within the Excel VBE (called "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications") I was not able to change shortcuts to any key combinations using the "Microsoft Excel.app". I think you are making a great point, but I've searched A LOT but don't see any way to bring up "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications" in the list of Apps available within Keyboard Shortcuts section of the System Preferences.